# WPF: why my slider not show the minimum value on my label

Tags: wpf, slider, styles

```
<Grid Margin="405,192,170,450" >
    <Slider Name="speedSlider" Value="1" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Minimum="0" Maximum=" 50" TickFrequency="5" TickPlacement="None" Width="160"/>
    <Label Name="lblSliderSpeed" Content="{Binding ElementName=speedSlider, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:#}"/>
</Grid>
```

My `label` show the current `slide` `value` while the `value` changing but at the `minimum value` (0) my `label` not shows any `value`

i also try this code behind and this still not helped although the if is executed:

```
private void speedSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        double value = speedSlider.Value;
        if (value == 0)
        {
            lblSliderSpeed.Content = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `ContentStringFormat` Change the `ContentStringFormat` to Like this

```
<Label Name="lblSliderSpeed" Content="{Binding ElementName=speedSlider, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:00}"/>
```

And No code Required In page Behind.

Because,The "#" custom format specifier serves as a digit-placeholder symbol. If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where the "#" symbol appears in the format string, that digit is copied to the result string. Otherwise, nothing is stored in that position in the result string.

For more Information '#' Formation [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierD) and for "0" Formation click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#Specifier0)

Answer (score 0):

Your String Format doesn't support zero, use this instead:

```
ContentStringFormat="{}{0:#; #;0}"
```

see [this link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-int/) for more information on String format for Int.